# How to receive mongodb array data in a javascript function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to use the google maps api push, however I need to pass the lat and lng data which is an array of number each, below I leave the code for how I have to go.

But how do I pass the mongodb data with nodejs like this to my code below?

It complains that it can not be used this way, within the javascript function.
I'm using: NODEJS + MONGODB + EJS + GOOGLE MAPS API

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
         * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
          height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        #info {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
      </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="info">
    </div>
    <%= for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) { %>
    <script>
      var map;
var qtPolygon = 0;
var polygonComplete = false;


function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['marker', 'polygon']
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            editable: true,
            clickable: true,
            fillColor: "#0000FF",
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        },
        markerOptions: {
            icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'
        },
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon;
    var points = new Array();



      points.push({
        lat: <%= tasks[i].coordenadasLat %>,
        lng: <%= tasks[i].coordenadasLng %>
      });

      polygon[i].setPath(points);
      polygon[i].setMap(map)

  }

    </script>
    <% } %>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRuw2dZRiWf45mKlCbmEz9XMlNrX45P4E&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

**IN MONGODB:**

```
db.db_mapbi.insert({"nome": "Bangu", "coordenadasLat": [-33.564,-35.259,-35.155], "coordenadasLng": [-33.564,-35.259,-35.155]})

db.db_mapbi.insert({"nome": "Bangu2", "coordenadasLat": [-33.564,-35.259,-35.155], "coordenadasLng": [-33.564,-35.259,-35.155]})
```

**LIBS**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db;

// CHAMADO QUANDO O {REQUIRE} É EXECUTADO
module.exports = function(){
    // IF {Db} não conter um valor válido
    // CRIA CONECÇÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS {MONGODB}, COM O {SCHEMA crud_exer}
    if(!db){
        db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_mapbi');
    }
    return db;
}
```

**ROUTES**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var model = require('./../model/tasks')(); // TRAZ O RETORNO, COM O MODEL PRONTO

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // BUSCA OS DADOS NO BANCO DE DADOS CRIADO
  model.find(null, function(err, tasks){
    if(err){
      throw err;
    }
    res.render('index', {title: 'CRUD - EXERCICIO', tasks: tasks})
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

**MODEL**

```
module.exports = function(){
    var db = require('./../libs/connect_db')();
    var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;

    var task = Schema({
        nome: String,
        coordenadasLat: Number,
        coordenadasLng: Number
    });

    return db.model('tasks', task);

}
```

Comment: So how would this be related to MongoDB? I cannot see any code that would point in this direction...? Also, please try to be more specific and only post relevant code fragments not just literally everything.

Comment: @dnickless I'm sorry, I posted all the code above.

Comment: We're getting closer. ;) What exactly is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Dnickless 
It does not find ".coordinatesLat" and ".coordinatesLng"

Comment: Where? In the block that starts with `points.push`?

Comment: @Dnickless, isto mesmo.